# Geb content elements unreachable in spock test: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: bdd, spock, functional-testing, spring-test, geb

I have been using Geb and Spock along side with Spring Boot it's all fine untill I decided to use Geb Page classes. Below is my spec test class details

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
class LoginSpec extends GebSpec{

  @LocalServerPort
  private int port
//....
}
```

The following test works

```
def "User should with valid username and password "() {
    def username
    def password
    def loginUrl

    given: "A valid username and password"
    username = "user"
    password = "password"
    loginUrl = "http://localhost:" +port+"/hello"

    when:
    go loginUrl

    then:
    browser.page.title == "Login"

    when:
    $("#loginForm input[name=username]").value(username)
    $("#loginForm input[name=password]").value(password)
    $("#loginForm input[type=submit]").click()


    then:
    $("h1", text: iContains("Hello $username"))

}
```

I have defined the LoginPage class as the following

```
import geb.Page

class ModeledLoginPage extends Page{

  static url = '/login'

  static at = { title == "Login"}

  static content = {

    loginForm { $("#loginForm")}
    formUsername { $("#loginForm input[name=username]") }
    formPassword { $("#loginForm input[name=password]") }
    formSubmitButton {
        loginForm.find("input", type: "submit")
    }
    errors {
        $(".alert-danger")
    }

    invalidUsernameOrPasswordError {
        errors.filter(text:contains("Invalid username and/or password"))
    }
  }


}
```

When I do a sad path of the same test that worked above with the following:

```
 def "User should not be able to login with wrong Username or Wrong Password " (){
    def uname
    def passwd

    given: "A wrong username and a correct password"
    uname = "wronguser"
    passwd = "password"
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:"+port

    when: "User navigates to the login page"
    to ModeledLoginPage

    then:
    at ModeledLoginPage

    when: "User enters the wrong username and correct password and clicked on submbit button"
    ModeledLoginPage.formUsername.value(uname)
    ModeledLoginPage.formPassword.value(passwd)
    ModeledLoginPage.formSubmitButton.click()


    then: "We are redirected back to login page and there is an error message wrong: Invalid username and/or password "
    at ModeledLoginPage
    ModeledLoginPage.invalidUsernameOrPasswordError.present
}
```

I have the following error : `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: formUsername for class: net.myname.tutorials.springbootsecurity.ModeledLoginPage at net.myname.tutorials.springbootsecurity.LoginSpec.User should not be able to login with wrong Username or Wrong Password (LoginSpec.groovy:80)`

I am a little bit lost here not able to pin point where the issue is. I have checked various post on StackOverflow and the Geb Book.

Below are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
 compile("com.h2database:h2")
 testCompile("junit:junit")
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
 testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4'
 testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11'
 testCompile "org.gebish:geb-core:2.1"
 testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:2.1"
 testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.6.0"
 testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.6.0"
```

}

Most grateful if anyone can shed some lights on this .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code to:

```
when: "User enters the wrong username and correct password and clicked on submbit button"
formUsername.value(uname)
formPassword.value(passwd)
formSubmitButton.click()


then: "We are redirected back to login page and there is an error message wrong: Invalid username and/or password "
at ModeledLoginPage
invalidUsernameOrPasswordError.present
```

See http://gebish.org/manual/current/#spock-junit-testng and http://gebish.org/manual/current/#the-page for an explanation.

If you wish to track current page type in order to get better authoring support from your IDE (mainly IntelliJ, see http://gebish.org/manual/current/#authoring-assistance-autocomplete-and-navigation), you might want to rewrite it to:

```
then:
def modeledLoginPage = at ModeledLoginPage

when: "User enters the wrong username and correct password and clicked on submbit button"
modeledLoginPage.formUsername.value(uname)
modeledLoginPage.formPassword.value(passwd)
modeledLoginPage.formSubmitButton.click()


then: "We are redirected back to login page and there is an error message wrong: Invalid username and/or password "
at(ModeledLoginPage).invalidUsernameOrPasswordError.present
```